# RegEx Matching Even Sets of Numbers

Tags: regex

I am having a bit of brain fog on this, perhaps one/some of you could provide me with some insight.

I'm trying to match double sets of digits `[0-9]`, between 1 and 5 sets, number order doesn't matter at all so `\d` will work just fine. Thus minimum number count would be 2 and maximum would be 10.

Valid example:

```
03
11
2112
1234
945312
234902
12481352
89024589
2348253415
1349843523
```

Invalid example:

```
1
123
23490
8902458
134984352
252049568278
234092538134123508
```

I thought about `/(\d{1,5}){2}/`, but that could match `123` which would be invalid for my use case.

The obvious solution is: `/(\d{2}|\d{4}|\d{6}|\d{8}|\d{10})/`

I'd like to know if there is a more graceful answer than my very baseline approach.

I purposely did not use `^` and `$` in my examples as this is part of a larger expression which I'm working on.  More specifically to match MGRS Easting and Northing number sets, there's some published code [on this gist line 57](https://gist.github.com/cgudea/7c558138cb48b36e785b#file-geodesy_regex-py-L57), but `^\d{1,2}[^ABIOYZabioyz][A-Za-z]{2}([0-9][0-9])+` would match more than 10 ending digits which is invalid.

Even more verbosely for clarity if you're unfamiliar with MGRS which I have a suspicion that many folks are.

```
1234567890
├───┘├───┘
│    └─ Northing
└────── Easting

12345678
├──┘├──┘
│   └─ Northing
└───── Easting

123456
├─┘├─┘
│  └─ Northing
└──── Easting

1234
├┘├┘
│ └─ Northing
└─── Easting

12
│└─ Northing
└── Easting
```

Comment: Something like `\b(\d{2}){1,5}\b`

Comment: Dang .. I love it when someone is like: oh that's easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use word boundaries since line start and end won't work for you based on the larger context. Then you just match between 1 and 5 groups of digit pairs. Something like:

```
\b(\d{2}){1,5}\b
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex:

```
\b(?:\d\d){1,5}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x3Me4g/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word Boundary
- `(?:\d\d){1,5}`: Match 1 to 5 sets of pair of digits
- `\b`: Word Boundary

Comment: The questioner specifically doesn't want ^$

Comment: Ah I missed out that part. Changed to `\b` now

Answer (score 1):

I'm no master of regex but could you possibly do something like `/(\d{2}){1,5}/` to require sets of 2 and allow 1-5 sets of those sets of 2?

Comment: This will match 12345678901234567890

Comment: Good point. Could this be slightly modified to `^(\d{2}){1,5}$` so that it starts and ends with the sets defined?

Comment: also precluded by the question. but on the right track. see benvc's answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I missed the section about not using ^ and $. Boundaries make sense then.